# Security implications of changing “perf_event_paranoid”

Tags: linux-kernel, profiling, perf

I'd like to use the `perf` utility to gather measurements for my program. It runs on a shared cluster machine with Debian 9 where by default the  `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` is set to 3, therefore disallowing me to gather measurements. Before changing it, I'd like to know what the implications of this are.

Is it just security that would allow other users to profile stuff run by other uses and therefore gain insights? We do not care about this as it is a inner circle of users anyway. Or is it performance perhaps, which will impact everyone else as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It’s only security, performance isn’t affected (at least, when `perf` isn’t running; and even then, `perf`’s impact is supposed to be minimal). Changing `perf_event_paranoid` doesn’t change the performance characteristics of the system, whether `perf` is running or not.

There’s a detailed discussion of [the security implications of `perf`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html) in the kernel documentation. The recommendation there is to set up a group for users with access to `perf`, and set `perf` up with the appropriate capabilities for that group, instead of changing `perf_event_paranoid`:

```
cd /usr/bin
groupadd perf_users
chgrp perf_users perf
chmod o-rwx perf
setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep perf
```

and add yourself to the `perf_users` group.

Version 5.8 of the kernel added a dedicated capability, so instead of granting all of `cap_sys_admin`, the last command can be reduced to

```
setcap cap_perfmon,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep perf
```

Comment: It should be noted on some Linux distributions (e.g. Ubuntu 18.04LTS) `/usr/bin/perf` is actually a `bash` script which calls the "real" `perf` binary for the current kernel. In order to get this to work in such cases you'll need to set the capabilities on that instead.